# what happens if there is no rock anywhere on the map?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dwarf Fortress: No stone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5185/dwarf-fortress-no-stone)

I mined through three whole levels and only found water and no rock.  I also managed to accidentally drain the dwarves water source, which was not good because now they have no water.

My question is: what happens if there is no rock anywhere? is there scope to continue or did I just really choose a bad place?

Comment: I am guessing that what happpened to you was you embarked on a map with a pond but no river, dug down to an aquifer and all the water in the pond drained away into it. If you channel any aquifer tiles you will get more water than you will ever need. And the stone you want is all hiding under that aquifer layer. Aquifers are one of the banes of DF players until they learn to deal with them, which is why most guides suggest new players avoid them during embark. More about aquifers here:  http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Aquifer. Trading for stone is one solution if it is rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chance that an embark square has no rock at all, especially in DF2010 is **very** small. You might just have to dig deeper or farther. See [Exploratory mining](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Exploratory_mining) for more information.

If, on the other hand, there are indeed no rocks, you can always trade for them and rock items you might need. For most things however you should be able to make do with wooden items.

Comment: Now, if you have no stone, and no wood... FUN!

Comment: So you could only grow plants?

Comment: The best thing about DF is you can make a living anywhere. You could grow lots of farms and make some awesome food to sell for some beds. Or bring some cages and start a breathing farm on exotic creatures. I don't believe there could be a setting where you can't survive.

Comment: Moved my comment from this answer to the OP question.